# Head Rotation in Opposite Direction with GLM and Oculus Rift SDK

Tags: opengl, rotation, glm-math, oculus

I am 90% there in getting orientation to work.

I am just trying to resolve one last bit and I hope someone can point me to any easy errors I am making but not seeing.

My code works except when a person looks left the camera actually rotates right. Vice versa with looking right, camera rotates left.

Any idea what I am doing wrong here?

I retrieve the orientation from the Oculus Rift like so:

```
OVR::Quatf OculusRiftOrientation = PredictedPose.Orientation;
glm::vec3 CurrentEulerAngles;
glm::quat CurrentOrientation;

OculusRiftOrientation.GetEulerAngles<OVR::Axis_X, OVR::Axis_Y, OVR::Axis_Z,
   OVR::Rotate_CW, OVR::Handed_R>
   (&CurrentEulerAngles.x, &CurrentEulerAngles.y, &CurrentEulerAngles.z);

CurrentOrientation = glm::quat(CurrentEulerAngles);
```

And here is how I calculate the LookAt:

```
/*

DirectionOfWhereCameraIsFacing is calculated from mouse and standing position so that you are not constantly rotating after you move your head.

*/

glm::vec3 DirectionOfWhereCameraIsFacing;
glm::vec3 RiftDirectionOfWhereCameraIsFacing;
glm::vec3 RiftCenterOfWhatIsBeingLookedAt;
glm::vec3 PositionOfEyesOfPerson;
glm::vec3 CenterOfWhatIsBeingLookedAt;
glm::vec3 CameraPositionDelta;

RiftDirectionOfWhereCameraIsFacing = DirectionOfWhereCameraIsFacing;
RiftDirectionOfWhereCameraIsFacing = glm::rotate(CurrentOrientation, DirectionOfWhereCameraIsFacing);
PositionOfEyesOfPerson += CameraPositionDelta;
CenterOfWhatIsBeingLookedAt = PositionOfEyesOfPerson + DirectionOfWhereCameraIsFacing * 1.0f;
RiftCenterOfWhatIsBeingLookedAt = PositionOfEyesOfPerson + RiftDirectionOfWhereCameraIsFacing * 1.0f;

RiftView = glm::lookAt(PositionOfEyesOfPerson, RiftCenterOfWhatIsBeingLookedAt, DirectionOfUpForPerson);
```

Comment: That means there is something wrong with rotation relative to your Y-axis (up vector). I am *guessing* that you can correct that by changing either `OVR::Rotate_CW` or `OVR::Handed_R` in the `OcculusRiftOrientation.GetEulerAngles` call.

Comment: Is this also happening after you rotate your Oculus more than 360° (Yaw) to the left / right? I had a similar problem and when turning the Oculus more than one spin the head tracking flipped sides and was mirrored ever since. Turning the Oculus again for 360° fixed it again. To Avoid that behaviour I used the sign of thepose.Orientation.w which fixed the problem for me. Maybe this helps.